# Xamarin : add .dll files at runtime to add functionnalities to application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, runtime, assemblies

I'm wondering if it's possible for a Xamarin application (all the platforms : Android, iOS, Windows Phone) to detect and load assemblies at runtime.

This is the kind of thing that I already did in WPF, and I'd like to use those modules (maybe with some modifications) in a Xamarin app.

I've spent yesterday looking for info online, and today I tried to implement a solution, but without success.

Prism seemed to be a way to do it, but it works only in WPF.

The restriction which makes this difficult is that I don't know at compile time any information about the assemblies. No names, no versions, no classes.
I can put the name and the version in the filename, and maybe find the classes by reflection. Using an interface as entry point (Prism use this), I should be able to do it.

Do you have any thoughts about this challenge ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- iOS: No

Apple does not allow code that was not bundled into the app at signing time to be executed, thus no on-the-fly Jit'ing of `CIL` allowed. The only exception to this is Javascript code that is run via their Nitro JavaScript Engine.

- Android: Yes

Google allows just about anything you can think of, for better or worse ;-)

- Windows Phone: No

All code must be signed as part of the Microsoft Store' App Ingestion process and thus you can not dynamically load assemblies later

**Note:** If this is a **hard** requirement for your app, you should look at hybrid mobile apps, like Cordova/Ionic, where you can perform a hot push to roll out new features, bugs fixes, etc... Besides self-hosting those hot pushes, various vendors support hosting of those, even Microsoft Azure  has a full versioning publication system for this. Of course you would most likely be coding in JavaScript (or some trans-compiled variant).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices. If I understand you properly, looking to build modules in JavaScript seems to work on each platform. I'll look into Cordova and Ionic and see if I can get something to work.